# MVC helper extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

why do i get the error " Expected class, interface, enum or struct" with string underlined?

```
 public static string IsSelected(this HtmlHelper helper, string A, string B)

    {
         return "wtf";

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your extension method needs to be inside a static class:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string IsSelected( this HtmlHelper helper, string A, string B)
    {
        return "wtf";

    }
}
```

Comment: that fixed one part, but it still is not registering as an extension with system.web.mvc.htmlhelpers. what else needs to be done?

Comment: actually, i imported namespace in view and it workes, but should i have to do that?

Comment: You can import the namespace in your web.config instead of the view itself.